# Finding smallest closed affine subspace

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Given the space $H=\mathbb{L}^2(0,1)$, and the subspace $K$ of $H$ defined by:
$$K=\left\{f\in H: f\geq 0\right\},$$
I would like to determine the smallest closed affine subspace of $H$ which contains $K$. My first thought is that the answer is $K$ itself, but I really don't know where the affine property comes into play? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS**. Since $K$ contains the null function $0$, the affine subspace you are after is actually a vector subspace. Note that $K$ itself is not a vector subspace, because if $f\in K$ then $-f$ needs not be in $K$.

Take an arbitrary function in $H$. Can you decompose it into a linear combinations of functions in $K$?

Comment: @user223935: You can do that if you want, but note that neither cos nor sin are in $K$. First, conjecture what the vector subspace you are after might be. Then, prove your conjecture.